# how to bind value on button click with [(ngModel)]

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-ngmodel

Here is my code which i am trying,

```
 <select id="myid" [(ngModel)]="updateId" class="form-control">
 <option value="U-001" >day </option>  
 <option value="U-002" >week</option>
 </select>
```

Am able to change the updateId and it's working fine with above code. But, i don't need any select drop down functionality. i want same functionality with button click. i have two buttons now as below

```
<div class="container">
<p> selected {{updateId}} </p>
    <button type="button home-button" id="button1" >Home</button>
    <button type="button contact-button" id="button2">Contact Us</button>
</div>
```

i want to bind the value whichever button user selects. Suppose if button1 clicks, it should bind ngmodel i.e updateId with "U-001"

Please suggest me how to achieve without any

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you're looking for, but you could assign values to variables in the event handlers.

```html
<button type="button home-button" (click)="updateId='U-001'" id="button1" >Home</button>
<button type="button contact-button" (click)="updateId='U-002'" id="button2">Contact Us</button>
```

#### Update: Set background color

There are multiple ways to set the styling of an element dynamically in Angular. For starters, you could look into [`ngClass`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) and [`ngStyle`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle). Here I've declared an object `buttons = { button1: false, button2: false }` with the keys being the corresponding element IDs that you've defined already. Then we could send the ID using template reference variables (`#buttonHome` and `#buttonContact` here) to an event handler like `onClick(buttonHome.id)`. In the handler, we loop through the buttons and flip the flag if the button is pressed. Finally we disable all button colors using the `blur` event.

Controller

```js
export class AppComponent  {
  updateId: string;
  buttons = { button1: false, button2: false }

  onClick(buttonId) {
    Object.keys(this.buttons).forEach(key => {
      if (key === buttonId) {
        this.buttons[key] = true;
      } else {
        this.buttons[key] = false;
      }
    });
  }

  onBlur() {
    Object.keys(this.buttons).forEach(key => {
      this.buttons[key] = false;
    });
  }
}
```

CSS

```css
button {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 40px;
  width: 80px;
  border: none;
  margin: 2px;
}

button,.unselected {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

button,.selected {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

Template

```html
<button 
  #buttonHome 
  [ngClass]="buttons.button1 ? 'selected' : 'unselected'" 
  type="button home-button" 
  (click)="updateId=='U-001'; onClick(buttonHome.id)" 
  (blur)="onBlur()" 
  id="button1"
>Home</button>

<button 
  #buttonContact 
  [ngClass]="buttons.button2 ? 'selected' : 'unselected'"  
  type="button contact-button" 
  (click)="updateId='U-002'; onClick(buttonContact.id)" 
  (blur)="onBlur()" 
  id="button2"
>Contact Us</button>
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4hijfu)

<sup>Since we're looping the collection of buttons for each button press and blur event, it might be slower if too many buttons are involved.</sup>

Comment: can i even change the color of that button?

Answer (score 0):

**In HTML**

```
<button type="button home-button" (click)="Update('U-001')" id="button1" >Home</button>

<button type="button contact-button" (click)="Update('U-002')" id="button2">Contact Us</button>
```

**In .ts class**

```
public updateId;

Update(value : string)
{
     this.updateId = value;
}
```